# Eclipse XWT in production?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, xwt

Have anybody used [Eclipse XWT](http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/XWT) in non-trivial (e.g. something more complex then tutorial) environment? I don't think Eclipse4 uses it by itself.

Does it really have any advantages over SWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, no one have seen XWT in production env.

Answer (score 1):

XWT is a declarative UI framework. It allows you to model your UI. You don't need to write code to instantiate, design, layout and data-bind your SWT widgets. Instead a XML based description file is used to build the UI.

Take a look at the example from the XWT FAQ: http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/XWT#Layout

XWT resembles GladeXML, XAML and XUL. There is tooling support in Eclipse Juno with the XWT Editor and WindowBuilder.

In my opinion the tooling support is lacking, several features of XWT are missing from the editors. While I generally prefer the declarative UI approach, I wouldn't base a non-trivial project on XWT alone.