# Documentation and Tutorials for XWT

Tags: java, swt, xwt

I'm currently in the design phase of a Java based project. The frontend is not overly complicated (consists of 4 to 5 separate composites/windows), meaning, it is certainly doable using plain SWT.

However, if possible, I'd like to further separate the GUI-Layout from functional code. At first glance, XWT seems to be just right for the job. The only issue with XWT is that I can't find any comprehensive tutorials or even proper documentation.

Does anyone know where I can find such material? Or should I simply give up and do the whole thing with SWT only?

PS: [1] is the only useful resource I could find so far...

[1] http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/XWT

Comment: I don't think anyone actually ever used XWT in real-world - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626639/eclipse-xwt-in-production

Comment: I think it's okay to discover without good tutorials, because it looks not very hard or complex. At least it may be simpler than messing with plain SWT.

Answer (score 1):

The project moved; the current pages are

1. http://www.eclipse.org/proposals/technology.xwt/
2. http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/257/

And no, I could not fnd any current tutorials.